# Import C++ function into teradata

Tags: c++, import, user-defined-functions, teradata

I have some C++ functions and which are used to check for valid decimal, date, timestamp etc. 
What I want is to import those functions as UDF into Teradata in order make use them in my SQLs. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are Scalar, (Windowed Aggregate) and Table UDFs, check the manuals:

[SQL External Routine Programming](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1147_112A/ch01.058.001.html).

There are some articles on Teradata's Developer Exchange covering that topic:

[How to Create and Debug a Scalar CUDF using Eclipse](http://developer.teradata.com/extensibility/articles/udf-debugging/debug-a-scalar-cudf-using-eclipse)